# Oreo lockscreen or distances not display notifications

Tags: android, push-notification

> Icon resource default not found. Notification will use default icon. 
>   Use of stream types is deprecated for operations other than volume
>   control  See the documentation of setSound() for what to use instead
>   with android.media.AudioAttributes to qualify your playback usecase

There is such a warning.I read all the texts there. but I could not solve the problem. still going on. notification occurs when the application is activated normally. there is no notification in the background.

```
public class FirebaseMessagingService extends com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static int value = 0;
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

        String notification_title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
        String notification_message = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
        value++;
        String click_action = remoteMessage.getNotification().getClickAction();

        String from_user_id = remoteMessage.getData().get("from_user_id");
        long[] pattern = {500,500,500,500};//Titreşim ayarı
        String CHANNEL_ID = "my_channel_01";
        String id = "my_channel_01";
        CharSequence name ="kanalın adı";
        String description = "acıklaması";
        int mNotificationId = 1;

        Intent intent;
        PendingIntent pendingIntent;
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

        if (mNotificationManager == null) {
            mNotificationManager =
                    (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

            NotificationChannel mChannel = mNotificationManager.getNotificationChannel(id);
            if (mChannel == null) {
                int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
                mChannel = new NotificationChannel(id, name, importance);
                mChannel.setDescription(description);
                mChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
                mChannel.enableVibration(true);

                AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                        .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                        .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION_RINGTONE).build();
                mChannel.setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION), audioAttributes);
                mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
            }
            builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, id);

            intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
            AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                    .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                    .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION_RINGTONE).build();

            builder.setContentTitle(notification_title)  // required
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher) // required
                    .setContentText(this.getString(R.string.app_name))  // required
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setTicker(notification_title)
                    .setVibrate(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
        } else {

            builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

            intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

            builder.setContentTitle(notification_title)                           // required
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher) // required
                    .setContentText(this.getString(R.string.app_name))  // required
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                    .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setTicker(notification_title)
                    .setVibrate(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400})
                    .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);
        } // else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

        Notification notification = builder.build();
        mNotificationManager.notify(mNotificationId, notification);
```

Comment: How to display notification ?

Comment: my still problem